# How to know the subscription is cancelled or trial is cancelled in stripe

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

Both trial end and subscription end through "customer.subscription.deleted" in webhook, so how I know that the trial is ended or subscription is ended.

(after free trial the subscription is automatically cancelled)
(No automatic payment after subscription ends)

Answer (score 0):

A Subscription is only automatically cancelled when a trial ends if payment for the upcoming interval fails and you've configured it in your Billing settings to automatically cancel the Subscription if payment fails.

Assuming you're using `collection_method=charge_automatically`,  You can tell from the webhook event if it was automatically cancelled after a trial because the payment failed by comparing [trial_end](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-trial_end) and [ended_at](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-ended_at) in customer.subscription.deleted. If the timing is the same, you can probably take this to mean that it was automatically cancelled when the trial ended.